# Setting up RAID1 with boot drive and additional drive

Tags: raid, windows-server-2003

Is it possible to set up raid1 after having installed Windows 2003 on one drive, if I have a matching additional harddrive?

I have never done this before, I do have both drives (60gb sata) hooked up to a pci raid controller (FastTrak® TX2300) that I looted from an older server, and they get detected fine.

If possible, what is the easiest way? Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the manufacturer of the card provides Windows software to "migrate" from non raid to Raid 1, then yes, some Intel raid controllers and software allow this, not sure about Promise, I suggest you contact Promise support for a definite answer on this.

http://www.promise.com/support/download.aspx?region=en-global&m=89&statistic=support

Promise does suppy "WebPam" software for Windows, maybe it allows for migration.

Select your Product then your Model, you will find the Software and other material for your product.

http://www.promise.com/support/download.aspx?m=89&region=en-global&rsn1=24

User Guide for the TX2300
http://www.promise.com/support/download_file.aspx?rsn=116&m=89&region=en-global

After looking through the guide, It appears there is no "migrate" function, it only allows you to set up a new raid volume using "free" logical drives,

.